# Highstock : Yaxis last horizontal label value not showing

Tags: label, highcharts

Im having an highStock chart that is not displaying the last yAxis horizontal line value.
Let's take a look on the picture as it shows the problem: It shows 299, 400, 600 but the last one is not displayed

http://s10.postimg.org/rlp7via7t/highstock.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set showLastLabel as true http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.showLastLabel